# Helm: How to convert a string with dot notation to a dict

Tags: helm3

I'm looking for a sane way to convert a string like

`topkey.nestedkey.morenestedkey`

to

```yaml
topkey:
  nestedkey:
    morenestedkey:
```

The input in values.yaml would be like:

```yaml
custom:
 - name: topkey.nestedkey.morenestedkey
   value: val1
 - name: topkey2.nestedkey2.morenestedkey2
   value: val2
```

So I would do something like this, but can't figure out the conversion.
(I know that I would probably need to check if the key exists before setting a value to it)

```yaml
{{- range $item := .Values.custom }}
???
{{ $_ := set ?? ?? $item.value }}
{{- end }}
```

Reasoning behind this is that the `custom` array is created via a GUI.
And instead of exposing each and every option of a yaml formated file,
I expose the most popular ones. But I want the interface to allow to add extra options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

values.yaml

```yaml
custom:
 - name: topkey.nestedkey.morenestedkey
   value: val1
 - name: topkey2.nestedkey2.morenestedkey2
   value: val2
```

templates/cm.yaml

```yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test
data: 
  data: |-
  {{- range $item := .Values.custom }}
  {{- $x := 4 }}
  {{- range ( split "." $item.name) }}
  {{- . | nindent (int $x) }}:
  {{- $x = (add 2 (int $x)) }}
  {{- end }}
  {{- $x = (add 2 (int $x)) }}
  {{- $item.value | nindent (int $x) }}
  {{- end }}
```

output.yaml

```yaml
---
# Source: test/templates/cm.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test
data: 
  data: |-
    topkey:
      nestedkey:
        morenestedkey:
            val1
    topkey2:
      nestedkey2:
        morenestedkey2:
            val2
```

(ps: Adjust the indent quantity according to the actual situation)

Comment: Wow, this was easier than I expected. I was looking in a wrong direction of using `set`
Thanks